# The communication between: A view, A viewModel, A useCase, A repository, A service, and A dao in a clean architecture (MVVM) for Android

Tags: android, android-livedata, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow, android-mvvm

Using the `monarchy realm` database, a `dao` gives `liveData.` A `repository` gives that `liveData` to a `useCase` as a `flow` using `.asFlow` on the `liveData.` The `useCase` needs to return the `flow` to a `ViewModel` after doing some `filter,` `map,` and other validations. The `ViewModel` collects the `flow` from the `useCase` and posts an update to a local `mutableLiveData.` A `view` observes the `liveData` form of the `mutableLiveData.` **The `View` receives the update!**

[image]

```
//fragment.kt
fun initObserver() {
    viewModel.itemsLiveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) { list ->
        onUpdateItems(list)
    }
}

//viewModel.kt
private val _itemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Items>>()
val itemsLiveData = _itemsLiveData

init {
    getItems()
}

fun getItems() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        useCase.getItems().collectLatest { items ->
            _itemsLiveData.postValue(items)
        }
    }
}

//usecase.kt (flow or callbackFlow or suspendCancellableCoroutine?)
suspend fun getItems(): callbackFlow<List<Items>> {
    repository.getItems().collectLatest { dbItems ->
        val validList = dbItems.filter { it.isValid() }.map { it.toUiModel() }
        if (validList.isNotEmpty()) {
            trySendBlocking(validList)
        } else {
            trySendBlocking(defaultList)
        }
    }
    
    //Cancel this coroutine scope and it's children.
    awaitClose {
        cancel()
    }
    
    //Close this channel. No more sending. Sending operation is closed.
    channel.close()
}

suspend fun apiCall() {
    val result = api.getItems()
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        val items = result.body()?.items
        if (items != null && items.isNotEmpty()) {
            repository.saveItems(items)
        }
    }
}

//repository.kt
suspend fun getItems() = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { dao.getItemsLiveData().asFlow() }
suspend fun saveItems(items: Items) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { dao.saveItems(items) }

//dao.kt
fun getItemsLiveData() = LiveData<Items>()
fun saveItems(items: Items)
```

However, I have several questions or doubts:

1. Is it causing any memory leakage?
2. Am I using the `flow` in the correct way?
3. Should I use `take(1)` or `first()` on the `repository.getItems()` in the `useCase`?
4. When no data is in the database, we return a default value. When the user opens the associated screen or does `pull To Refresh,` we would make an API call and save the data to the database. I believe the update will travel in the following order: From the database to the `repository,` to the `useCase,` to the `ViewModel,` to the `fragment.` But I doubt the `useCase` as it cancels the scope and closes the channel. I suspect that it will not receive any update until we call `useCase.getItems` **again** that start collecting the flow from the `repository.` Is it right? If it is, how can we set up the entire communication so that the `fragment` always receives the update whenever there is a change in the database without calling the `useCase.getItems` function again after making an API call?
5. Should I use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead of the `callbackFlow` for such a requirement?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways i'd suggest you improve your code:

1. i don't know your db, therefore i can't really comment on that.
   However, i'd try to get a flow from the db, not a livedata. (Livedata was made for ui-related purposes, not db-stuff)
2. prefer variables to getFunctions()
   This way, if two parties try to access the same items, they actually use the same.

   ```
   // your repository will then be sth.like this:
   val items: Flow<List<Item>> = ...
   ```
3. Your usecase is far to complicated. Try something like this:

   ```
   val items: Flow<List<Item>> = repository.items
       .map { list -> 
           val filteredList = list
               .filter { it.isValid }
               .map { it.toUiModel() }

           if(filteredList.isEmpty()) defaultList else filteredList
       }
   ```
4. Your `viewModel` might just forward the data to the ui in the moment:
   val items: Flow<List> = usecase.items
5. In your fragment, you can then collect the items like specified here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda . This does all the handling of lifecycle & pausing flow collection etc.
6. Naming: Should `Items` really be plural?
7. in our company, we do the mapping dbModel -> domainModel in the repository. Is there a reason you're doing it in the usecase?
8. about "how to update" the data:
   Ui -> viewModel -> useCase -> repository. Repository will call api, and save the new data in the db.
   The updated data should then be automatically forwarded to the ui via the item chain we setup above.
9. Just in case you're just starting out with an app: ditch fragments for Jetpack Compose, since that is the future of android ui.